# which deep learning framework to use for generating predictive images

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

say you have a dataset of relatively similar images and for each image, the first half of the image is the input and the second half would be the output of the model. In other word you want to teach the model the first half of a single image, and have it generate the second half. which framework would best suit this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read about Generative Adversarial Networks (GANs). Then use either PyTorch 
 or Tensorflow on Python, though PyTorch is pretty famous for GANs.

Answer (score 1):

Pytorch deep learning framework should work for you as it has many research community support and many of the deep learning algorithm at the research stage are implemented in Pytorch.

Regarding the task mentioned you should try out GAN's and mentioning below some specific GANS algorithm :

- [DCGAN from official pytorch repo.](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/dcgan_faces_tutorial.html)
- [DCGAN Unofficial implementation](https://github.com/znxlwm/pytorch-MNIST-CelebA-GAN-DCGAN)